# Hashing used by Hashtable?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

What kind of hashing methodoly is used in `Hashtable` implementation in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java the `Object` class defines a method `int hashCode()`. Each class implements this differently, or not at all. The default implementation is to call `System.identityHashCode(this)`.

`Hashtable` uses the value returned by `hashCode()`, but truncates it according to the table size.

By the way, `Hashtable` is old. If you want to use it, you should use `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that, internally, both `HashMap` and `HashTable` use linked list buckets for collision resolution, rather than secondary or tertiary hashing.

Answer (score 3):

@Bart is correct, but I wanted to show you how you can discover this from the source code of `Hashtable`. The source is available [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html). Search for `hash(` and you find this function:

```
119           public int getKeyHash() {
120               return key.hashCode();
121           }
```

If we look a few lines up, we find that `key` is any `Object`:

```
 89       private static class Entry<K, V> extends MapEntry<K, V> {
 90           Entry<K, V> next;
```

We then look at a random class such as `String` and find it has a [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) method. We then also look at the `Object` class to find it *also* has a [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method. Therefore any object (since they all inherit from `Object`) has a `hashCode()` method.

Out of curiosity, we have a look at the [source for `Object`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html) and find this:

```
 33     public int hashCode() {
 34         return VMMemoryManager.getIdentityHashCode(this);
 35     }
```

Bingo!